# Multiple elements with same name but different types

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have XML I created which shows the responses from a survey.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl'?>
<survey>
    <questions>
        <question id="1">When did you start playing Pokemon Go?</question>
        <question id="2">What type of phone/OS do you play on?</question>
        <question id="3">What team are you on?</question>
        <question id="4">What Level Are You?</question>
        <question id="5">How many pokemon have you caught?</question>
        <question id="6">How many KM have you traveled? (Jogger medal)</question>
    </questions>
    <responses>
        <response id="1">
            <answer question="1">June</answer>
            <answer question="2">Android</answer>
            <answer question="3">Mystic (Blue)</answer>
            <answer question="4">25</answer>
            <answer question="5">0 to 1000</answer>
            <answer question="6">Silver</answer>
        </response>
        <response id="2">
            <answer question="1">June</answer>
            <answer question="2">Android</answer>
            <answer question="3">Mystic (Blue)</answer>
            <answer question="4">32</answer>
            <answer question="5">0 to 1000</answer>
            <answer question="6">Silver</answer>
        </response>
        ... More responses...
    </responses>
</survey>
```

### XSD (Only questions element)

```
<xs:element name="questions">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="question">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" 
                                             type="xs:int" use="required" 
                                             fixed="1"/>    
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="question">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" 
                                             type="xs:int" use="required" 
                                              fixed="2"/>   
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="question">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" 
                                             type="xs:int" use="required" 
                                             fixed="3"/>    
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="question">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" 
                                             type="xs:int" use="required" 
                                              fixed="4"/>   
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="question">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" 
                                             type="xs:int" use="required" 
                                             fixed="5"/>    
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="question">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" 
                                             type="xs:int" use="required" 
                                             fixed="6"/>    
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
```

My schema keeps giving me an error saying I have multiple elements with the same name, but different types when I try to validate it against my XML. 
Now I asked a question on here about my design of my XML and was told that it would be really stupid to ever use different elements with   etc. That is why I repeated the element name, but with an identifying attribute for each one.

Is there any workaround that doesn't involve redesigning the XML?

Answer (score 1):

The XSD constraint called "element declarations consistent" explicitly says that you cannot have two sibling elements with the same name but different types.

Are you really sure you want a fine-grained schema like this, where changing the questions in your questionnaire requires changing the schema?

If you do want to do it you could use the "conditional type assignment" feature in XSD 1.1 (aka type alternatives) where you make the type of a `question` element dependent on the value of the @id attribute.

But the whole design feels wrong to me. I would go for a generic schema that describes any possible questionnaire.

Comment: Well the problem is that I've been tasked with making sure each question is only answered with certain answers.
Question 1: any of the 12 months of the year
Question 2: any of {“Android”, “iOS”, “Both”}
etc. So those have to be inserted into the schema. It can't really be generic.

Comment: I don't think I would use XSD for this purpose. But this is obviously a student assignment (XML questionnaires always are) and one has to accept that the choice of technologies for a student assignment is made for pedagogical rather than engineering reasons.

Comment: Do you think it would be best to just call each <question> and <answer> element by <question1> <answer1> etc?

Comment: I can't answer that without thinking about the design of the whole application: how are questionnaires designed, how are they completed, how are the responses analysed, what happens when responses are invalid. I simply don't know what role your instance document and your schema play in the grand scheme of things. And I'm not going to get involved in the requirements analysis.